# Were other Jedi Temples inhabited? (Canon/Legends)

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, jedi-training

Well, I mean we know that the main Jedi Headquarters by the time of the Clone Wars is the one that was built on Coruscant, but we also know there were other temples spread out across the galaxy. Were these temples in use like the one Coruscant? With Jedi living and being trained in them?

Other Jedi temples included:

A temple located on Tython.

The temple on Ilum.

The temple on Vrogas Vas.

The temple on Ossus.

A temple on Dantooine.

The temple on Lothal.

The Temple of Eedit on Devaron.

The temple on Ledeve.

The Temple of the Force on Ashas Ree.

Comment: What time period are you asking? Because during the Old Republic Era temples were populated.

Comment: @A.bakker I thought it was clear in the question but I guess I was wrong, I'm talking about the Clone Wars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the depictions I'm familiar with, the various Jedi temples were not inhabited during the Clone Wars.

For example, consider the temple on Lothal. The character's dialogue imply that the Jedi active during the Clone Wars were largely unaware of it; without the records maintained in the Jedi library, it could have been forgotten about completely. This is reinforced by the fact the temple on Lothal is hidden beneath a rock formation - not something you would likely do if the temple was still inhabited.

This video shows how it was hidden and what was needed to open it:

It's unclear if these temples ever were inhabited. They are not depicted as having facilities such as dormitories and kitchens that would be needed to house permanent residents. Instead, they may simply be shrines built in areas strong with The Force for specific purposes, such as rituals or retreats.

Regardless of whether these temples were occupied in the earlier days of the Republic, the evidence suggests that, in the time of the Clone Wars, these temples were relics of a bygone era that had been sealed and abandoned long ago.